# JPA/Hibernate - can we not retrieve a collection that is defined as a Set from our entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity like :

```
@Entity
public class Book{
    int bookId;
    @ManyToMany
    Set<Page> favoritePages;
   // getters/setters
}
```

`Page` is also an entity. Now if I write a query :

```
EntityManager em = // somehow get the entity manager
TypedQuery<Page> query = "Select favoritePages from Book where bookId=:id";
query.setParameter("id",2);

List <Page> pages = query.getResultList();
```

Now, this gives me an error that

> Type specified for TypedQuery (Pages) is incompatible with query
>   return type [interface java.util.Set]

***I can't change the type of favoritePages to a list***. How can I retrieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other alternatives, you can do:

```
TypedQuery<Book> query = "from Book where bookId=:id";
query.setParameter("id",2);
Set<Page> pages = query.getSingleResult().getFavoritePages();
```

But it also has its drawbacks, because you are only interested in querying the favorite pages.

Comment: "return new HashSet(query.getResultList());" I don't think this would work as the error is not in the casting of resultList but in the execution of the query